# JaxB Method for dealing with sub element

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Currently I have xml that looks like this:

```
<Person>
  <ID>e5b160d07</ID>
  <Source>
    <Name>HardImpact</Name>
  </Source>
</Person>
```

And my JaxB looks like:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Person")
public class PersonDTO {
  private String id;
  private Source source;

  @XmlElement(name="ID")
  public void setId(String id) {...}


  @XmlElement(name="Source")
  public void setSource(Source source) {...}

}

@XmlRootElement(name="Source")
class Source {
  private String name;

  @XmlElement(name="Name", namespace=DTOConstants.cmnv3)
  public void setName(String name) {...}
}
```

Is there a better way to use annotations to remove the need to have the class Source?  Modifying the incoming XML is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK Each Parent Tag should be an Entity to hold child tags as Attributes.

So your approach is a clean, common and preferred way to implement it. There are no Tags which automatically create the Source class,

but

you can use `@XMLAnyElement` to map the `Source` tag to an Object type. [Refer this example for more info on this tag.](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/using-xmlanyelement-to-build-generic.html)